# Compare two strings and return values that are not present in both

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I need (in `JavaScript`, maybe using `RegEx`? or some `React` component) to compare two strings and bold all the words/chars are not present in the "source" string.

For example:

"*business plan*" compared with "*business plafond*", should return "*business pla**fond***"

"*business plan*" comprared with "*plan and monitoring*" should return "*plan **and monitoring***"

Currently I use this method which works but unfortunately not in all cases, I can't find the issue:

```
compareStrings(a, b) {
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let result = "";

while (j < b.length)
{
    if (a[i] === ' ') {
        i++;
    } else {
        if ((a[i] != b[j]) || (b[j] === ' ') || i == a.length)
            result += b[j];
        else i++;
        // }
    }

    j++;
}
        return result;
    }
```

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: What "business plan" compared with "prefix plan postfix" should return?

Comment: It's a good question, the better thing would be if it returns "_**prefix** plan **postfix**_"

Comment: Hm... So "business plan" compared with "prefix plapostfix" should return "**prefix** pla**postfix**"? And what if we reduce to a single letters? Which of three "p" should be considered as related to word "plan"?
It seems the task doesn't have strict enough requirements in order to solve it.

Comment: @SergeyMell yeah, you're right... So what do you think could be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, I would suggest the following string comparison strategy:

- Consider having to strings `a` and `b`
- Take `b` character by character and find its first occurrence in `a`
- If there is a mismatch, try to find another offset in `a` where `b` still occurs
- If no such offset occurs anymore, you found the longest common character sequence and can begin marking the remaining characters of `b` in bold

If this is what you would like to achieve, you could try the following improvements on your algorithm:

```
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  let search = '';  // current search term (substring of b)

  while (j < b.length) {
    search += b[j];  // add another character of b to search string
    if (a.indexOf(search) > -1) {  // search is found in b, continue
      j++;
    } else {
      return b.substr(j);  // return remaining substring of b which is not part of a
    }
  }
}

console.info(compareStrings('business plan', 'business plafond'));  // fond
console.info(compareStrings('business plan', 'plan and monitoring')); // and monitoring
```

I've seen that in your original code you also want to skip space characters; however I didn't quite understand whether this behavior would result in erroneous outputs... If you want to ignore whitespace at all, try to use `a.replace(/\s/g)` (resp. with `b`).

Comment: It works, maybe i have to do more tests but this way is better for now!

Comment: If you have another issue with the algorithm, please edit your question and refine the comparison strategy so that we can improve the code further.

Answer (score 0):

Doing text diffs is actually a pretty complicated task, and you might need to fine-tune various parameters of how the diff is performed to get the results you want. I recently tried this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff

And found it to be pretty helpful.